# Maven Shade Plugin: how 'mvn install' can include in the local repository the same jar generated through 'mvn package'?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin

Having the following situation:

- STS
- Java
- Maven

### Machine One

#### workspace-01

The Java app with Maven is based for a **single** module.

Through either `mvn package` or `mvn install` for the app the respective jar is generated. Of course both are the same, but we have the solid confidence that the most valid or stable is the available through the local repository.

Now through `mvn install` the jar is installed in the local repository and using a *script* and referring the local repository is possible find and copy the `master-project.jar` file in other Machine and then is installed manually. It for simplicity purposes.

The point is: that for the other project that dependency can be used in peace how

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.manuel.jordan</groupId>
  <artifactId>master-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1.SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Until here all work fine

#### workspace-02

The app grew up and in other workspace the app was migrated to work with **multi-modules**

Lets assume the following structure for simplicity

```
master-project (<packaging>pom</packaging>)
alpha (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
beta (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
numbers (<packaging>pom</packaging>)
   one (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
   two (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
countries (<packaging>pom</packaging>)
   Europe (<packaging>pom</packaging>)
      France (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
      Italy (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
   AmericaLatina (<packaging>pom</packaging>)
      Peru (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
      Argentina (<packaging>jar</packaging>)
uber-jar (<packaging>jar</packaging>) <--- it has a special purpose
```

I am able to compile all these modules. Therefore *build success*

Now the `uber-jar` module has the unique purpose to define all the dependencies based on `<packaging>jar</packaging>` type to generate the uber jar through the `maven shade plugin`. The configuration is as follows:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
  <name>uber-jar</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.manuel.jordan</groupId>
    <artifactId>master-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan</groupId>
        <artifactId>alpha</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan</groupId>
        <artifactId>beta</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.manuel.jordan</groupId>
        <artifactId>etc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-fat-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>master-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

With the current configuration shown above if `mvn package` is executed in the `uber-jar`'s `target` directory appears the `master-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `uber-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` files. Until here, about the former, it is the same behaviour than the one module approach/enviroment.

If `mvn install` is executed, I can see in the local repository that each module is represented through a directory, where for each `<packaging>jar</packaging>` type it contains its respective jar file. Even I go the `uber-jar`'s directory in the local repository it appears its own jar, just that.

The point is that the *script* now fails because does not exist the `master-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the local repository anymore. Of course I can work around to the one generated in the `uber-jar`'s `target` directory. The other approach is use the same set of dependencies in the `uber-jar` module in the other project, but it is verbose.

**Observation:** that project should be not aware that the dependency comes from either *single-module* or *multi-module* project.

### Machine Two

The following must remain in peace in the other project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.manuel.jordan</groupId>
  <artifactId>master-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1.SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Request**: *if is possible*, How to edit the Maven Shade Plugin configuration shown above. It with the purpose to include the target's jar into the local repository

The unique solution is install manually the `master-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file available in the `uber-jar`'s `target` directory. But being curious if my request can be accomplished or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably noticed yourself, `<finalName>` only changes the name of the artifact in `target`. To change the name in the local repository, you need to change the Maven coordinates in the POM.

More importantly, copying from one local repository to another is not a recommended approach. Instead, the standard approach is to use a Nexus or Artifactory server.